# Vertex AI Custom Chatbot

Tags: chatbot, google-cloud-vertex-ai

In the code section, the examples are organized in InputOutputTextPair. Is there a way to configure it, so that the Input/Output reads entire conversation with a multiple inputs/outputs per example? Right now, the 1 input to 1 output format is limiting the information I can put in.